# rendering a custom entity

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I have a custom entity 'sponsor'.

I want to create a custom template for that entity. But I still want to use the formatter settings that have been defined in the UI.

So

- I set the viewbuilder to the default EntityViewBuilder in my annotation
- I defined the theme hook 'sponsor' in my .module file

  ```
  function sponsors_theme(){
  $theme_hook= array(
      'sponsor'=>array(
          'variables'=>array(
              'sponsor'=>null,


          ),

          'template'=>'sponsor',
      )
  );

  return $theme_hook;
  ```

  }
- Then I created my sponsor.html.twig file

Now I can access the raw values through {{sponsor.field.value}}

But I don't want to access all fields through their raw values. I still want to use the formatters.

Is there anyone who can tell me how to do that or point me to the right docs?

Matt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could craft a variable that holds all entity fields with respect to their order and formatter settings.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function sponsor_theme() {
  return [
    'sponsor' => [
      'render element' => 'elements',
    ],
  ];
}

/**
 * Prepares variables for sponsor templates.
 */
function template_preprocess_sponsor(&$variables) {
  // Helpful $content variable for templates.
  $variables['content'] = [];
  foreach (Element::children($variables['elements']) as $key) {
    $variables['content'][$key] = $variables['elements'][$key];
  }
}
```

This approach is used by core entities (node, user, comment etc).

Comment: Correct, but that's just one, what's important for this is to define your theme entry with render element => elements.  See also https://www.drupal.org/node/2808481, that will provide a default entity template with suggestions and everything that's needed, so zero custom code is required to display a content entity with fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I had been searching for this for a long time. Good thing this will be kind of automated through the default entity template. Good idea!